# Foreach multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have these input data that i stored in array before inserting into database.

```
$regData = array (
    'user_type'        => $_SESSION['user']->user_type,
    'user_id'          => $_SESSION['user']->id,
    'child_id'         => $this->input->post('child_name[]'),
    'tc_id'            => $this->input->post('tc_id'),
    'tc_sources'       => $this->input->post('tc_sources'),
    'tc_created_date'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
);
```

The output for `$regData` in array :

```
Array
(
    [user_type] => parent
    [user_id] => 5
    [child_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47
            [1] => 49
        )

    [tc_id] => 11
    [tc_sources] => Email
    [tc_created_date] => 2017-07-26 21:56:57
)
```

I am trying to `foreach` the array to make sure that it can be inserted into different row in the table as follow :

```
foreach ($regData as $k) {
    foreach ($k as $val) {
        $newArr[] = array(
            'user_type'        => $val['user_type'],
            'user_id'          => $val['user_id'],
            'child_id'         => $val['child_id'],
            'tc_id'            => $val['tc_id'],
            'tc_sources'       => $val['tc_sources'],
            'tc_created_date'  => $val['tc_created_date'],
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is the output of the **array form** that I want, but the data all having the same value, I don't really know how to foreach the array to get the exact data after loop :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_type] => 4
            [user_id] => 4
            [child_id] => 4
            [tc_id] => 4
            [tc_sources] => 4
            [tc_created_date] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_type] => 4
            [user_id] => 4
            [child_id] => 4
            [tc_id] => 4
            [tc_sources] => 4
            [tc_created_date] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: why not concat the array vals to be a csv string ?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs do you mean like using `implode`?

Comment: yar - if you do that you can change an array of ids to be 23,24,25 then explode on the , when you want it as an array again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code,

```
if(!empty($regData['child_id'])) {
    foreach($regData['child_id'] as $key => $row) {
       $newArr[$key]['user_type'] = $regData['user_type'];
       $newArr[$key]['user_id'] = $regData['user_id'];
       $newArr[$key]['child_id'] = $row;
       $newArr[$key]['tc_id'] = $regData['tc_id'];
       $newArr[$key]['tc_sources'] = $regData['tc_sources'];
       $newArr[$key]['tc_created_date'] = $regData['tc_created_date'];
   }
}
```

Output is below,

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [user_type] => parent
        [user_id] => 5
        [child_id] => 47
        [tc_id] => 11
        [tc_sources] => Email
        [tc_created_date] => 2017-07-26 16:27:49
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [user_type] => parent
        [user_id] => 5
        [child_id] => 49
        [tc_id] => 11
        [tc_sources] => Email
        [tc_created_date] => 2017-07-26 16:27:49
    )

)
```

Do you get output above? if it is not, please describe your question and sample output by comment.

Comment: Nailed it! That's what I'm looking. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you called your variable `$k`, I guess you assumed it would be your array's keys, but it will be the values instead.

The second issue is that your array `$regData` seems to only contain one entry, so you don't even need your foreach at all

This should work :

```
    $newArr[] = array(
        'user_type'        => $regData['user_type'],
        'user_id'          => $regData['user_id'],
        'child_id'         => $regData['child_id'],
        'tc_id'            => $regData['tc_id'],
        'tc_sources'       => $regData['tc_sources'],
        'tc_created_date'  => $regData['tc_created_date'],
    );
```

If you made a mistake in your answer and `$regData` contains indeed multiple entries, then this should work :

```
foreach ($regData as $val) {
    $newArr[] = array(
        'user_type'        => $val['user_type'],
        'user_id'          => $val['user_id'],
        'child_id'         => $val['child_id'],
        'tc_id'            => $val['tc_id'],
        'tc_sources'       => $val['tc_sources'],
        'tc_created_date'  => $val['tc_created_date'],
    );
}
```

Use `foreach ($regData as $k => $val) {}` to also get the keys :

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($regData as $entry) {
    foreach ($entry as $key => $val) {
        $newEntry[$key] = $val;
    }
    $newArr[] = $newEntry;
}
```

Or maybe better :

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($regData as $entry) {
    foreach ($entry as $key => $val) {
        $newArr[$entry['user_id']][$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

Provided your `user_id` are unique values.

Comment: I've tried this foreach but the output is not correct

Comment: I've spotted a mistake, I edited right after and added some more cases that might help you more or at least give you some ideas.